# How to manage CITemperatureAndTint filter using one uislider (-10 to 10) Range I need to change to warm if 10 and cooler if -10?

Tags: ios, swift

I created filter

How to manage CITemperatureAndTint filter using one uislider (-10 to 10) Range I need to change to warm if 10 and cooler if -10? I need to change color only not tint!

```
let tempFilter = CIFilter(name: "CITemperatureAndTint")
tempFilter?.setValue(brightnessOutput, forKey: "inputImage")

        //Warm
        
tempFilter?.setValue(CIVector(x: 6500, y: 500), forKey: "inputNeutral")
tempFilter?.setValue(CIVector(x: 1000, y: 630), forKey: "inputTargetNeutral")

let tempOutput = tempFilter?.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
    
outputImage = tempOutput
let output = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent)!
let result = UIImage(cgImage: output)
imgEditedFile = result
```

How to manage using uislider

Comment: You need a function which handles slider changes. You can add this function via slider.addTarget() .Or if you are using storyboard, create an outlet function.
Then move your filter logic into a function and replace your hardcoded values with function parameter variables. Then you call this function with the values from the slider.

Comment: @Erik I have the value slider and functions and how i can add it through filter its has 4 input values.